# Detemine the asymptotic growth of $(a_n)_n$ for $a_n = a_{n-1}+4a_{n-2}+2a_{n-3}$

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, power-series, generating-functions

> Detemine the asymptotic growth of $(a_n)_n$ for $a_n = a_{n-1}+4a_{n-2}+2a_{n-3}$ and $a_0 =1$, $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 5$, $a_3 = 11$.

I have already computed the following closed form expression for the OGF $A(z)$ of $(a_n)_n$:

$$A(z) = \frac{1}{1-z-4z^2-2z^3}.$$

My idea would now be to rewrite $A(z)$ in the form of a power series, extract the coefficient $a_n$ and then make the estimate. However, I do not see how to find said power series. I realise that the Generalised Binomial Theorem might be useful here, but I do not see how to apply it. Could you please help me?

Comment: The condition on a3 is redundant no?

Comment: Yeah, I just added it in case someone wants numerical values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By solving the [characteristic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients#Characteristic_polynomial_and_roots) $z^3-z^2-4z-2=0$ we find that the three roots are real and distinct: $-1$, $1+\sqrt{3}$ and $1-\sqrt{3}$. Therefore
$$a_n=C_1(-1)^n+C_2(1+\sqrt{3})^n+C_3(1-\sqrt{3})^n \qquad (*)$$
where $C_1,C_2,C_3$ are suitable constants which can be found using the initial terms:
$$\begin{cases}
C_1+C_2+C_3=1\\
C_1(-1)+C_2(1+\sqrt{3})+C_3(1-\sqrt{3})=1\\
C_1(-1)^2+C_2(1+\sqrt{3})^2+C_3(1-\sqrt{3})^2=5
\end{cases}$$
It turns out that $C_1=1$, $C_2=-C_3=1/\sqrt{3}$.

The closed formula $(*)$ can be obtained also by using the generating function $A(z)$ (and [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)):
$$A(z)= \frac{1}{1-z-4z^2-2z^3}=\frac{1}{1+z}+\frac{1/\sqrt{3}}{1-(1+\sqrt{3})z}-\frac{1/\sqrt{3}}{1-(1-\sqrt{3})z}$$
and recalling that $\frac{1}{1-az}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(az)^n$.

Since $1+\sqrt{3}$ is the largest root in modulus, it follows that the asymptotic growth  is
$$a_n\sim \frac{(1+\sqrt{3})^n}{\sqrt{3}}.$$
The sequence appears in OEIS as [A127864](https://oeis.org/A127864).